# jquery .height() not pulling the height

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the height of a div by getting the height from another div but it doesn't seem to use the height.

```
 $(".question-toggler").click(function() {
   $("#main-content-pane").height()
   $(".zebra-helper").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").height("#main-content-pane");
 });

 $(".handler").click(function() {
   $(".zebra-helper").hide("slow", "linear");
 });
```

Comment: did you forget to ask anything or was your intention just to let us know something!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're wanting -

```
 $(".question-toggler").click(function() {
   var cHeight = $("#main-content-pane").height();
   $(".zebra-helper").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").height(cHeight);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one-liner, try this:

```
$(".zebra-helper").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").height($("#main-content-pane").height());
```

If you want to use again the same height in that block, store it into a variable, then use it when needed:

```
var h = $("#main-content-pane").height();
$(...).height(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `height()` returns an integer, so **what do you want to do with that value?**

Store it in a variable:

```
var h = $("#main-content-pane").height();
$(".zebra-helper").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").height(h);
```

or inline (I don't like this method):

```
$(".zebra-helper").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").height($("#main-content-pane").height());
```

From documentation:

### `.height()`

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the height of every matched element. [**read more**](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 2):

What they said. The height() function only understands integers, not DOM objects (#main-content-pane), so you need to store it in a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a variable for height and use it.

```
$(".question-toggler").click(function() {
   var someheight = $("#main-content-pane").height()
   $(".zebra-helper").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").height(someheight);
 });
```